# CGAffineTransformMakeScale animate in and then out does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I am trying to animate in a view and then later animate it out. My code looks like this

```
- (void) animateIn{
    self.contentView.alpha = 0.0;
    self.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.6 initialSpringVelocity:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
        self.contentView.alpha = 1.0;
        self.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    } completion:nil];
}

- (void) animateOut{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        self.contentView.alpha = 0.0;
        self.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
    }];
}
```

The animation in works great. The animation out does not. The animation out looks like the view grows really fast.

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: In `animateOut`, you should omit the first two lines: `self.contentView.alpha = 1.0; self.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;`

Comment: That did not change anything. But I will remove it from the example to keep it simple.

Comment: Yes, I know it changes nothing. It was a comment, not the answer to your question.